# unable to Save Changes in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am currently doing some programming on Visual Studio 2013. It was working fine until it suddenly unable to save changes I made on my program. I can't figure out what happened for it was all so sudden that after I successfully run the program, edited some codes (removed a label), then run the program again, changes cannot be seen on the program I run. You can see the changes on the design but not during the program is running. Can someone tell me what to do so that I save changes on the running program? Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you still on debugging mode? maybe try stop debugging first?

Comment: I am not on the debugging mode. I already tried restarting my PC but still, I cant see the changes I made on the running program.

I tried my other visual Studio Projects and editing works on them. I just can't figure out what to check on this project to enable changes on it.

Comment: What type of program is it? Is it a web application, a Windows application, or some other type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how this one worked but running other Visual Studio 2013 Projects solved the issue.

Please leave comments on this answer if you know how running other VS 2013 projects solved the issue. :)

Comment: Is it possible that you opened a file with the same name but from another folder? In that case you have been modifying a file that your solution was not taking into account. Closing that file and reopening the file from the Solution Explorer would have fixed the problem, if that was your case.
Did you previously verify that the file you modified was the one of the project you were building?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably that project you are referring to might not have built successfully when you ran the project after the changes. Even if you save the changes, if the project is not built after changes are made, you won't see the changes in runtime. Please refer this to see about setting [Build Options in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyhcc7zc.aspx)...